# Python pandas: sum item occurences in a string list by item substring

Tags: python, pandas

I've this list of strings:

```
list = ['a.xxx', 'b.yyy', 'c.zzz', 'a.yyy', 'b.xxx', 'a.www']
```

I'd like to count items occurences by item.split('.')[0].

Desiderata:

```
a 3
b 2
c 1
```

Comment: Could you show what you've tried?

Comment: Why do you need a Pandas solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***setup***
*I don't like assigning to variable names that are built-in classes*

```
l = ['a.xxx', 'b.yyy', 'c.zzz', 'a.yyy', 'b.xxx', 'a.www']
```

***option 1***

```
pd.value_counts(pd.Series(l).str.split('.').str[0])
```

***option 2***

```
pd.value_counts([x.split('.', 1)[0] for x in l])
```

***option 3***
*wrap `Counter` in `pd.Series`*

```
pd.Series(Counter([x.split('.', 1)[0] for x in l]))
```

***option 4***

```
pd.Series(l).apply(lambda x: x.split('.', 1)[0]).value_counts()
```

***option 5***
*using `find`*

```
pd.value_counts([x[:x.find('.')] for x in l])
```

---

*All yield*

```
a    3
b    2
c    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `list` is not a good variable name because you will shadow the built in list. I don't know much `pandas`, but since it is not required here I'll post an answer anyway.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = ['a.xxx', 'b.yyy', 'c.zzz', 'a.yyy', 'b.xxx', 'a.www']
>>> Counter(x.split('.', 1)[0] for x in l)
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try the Counter class from collections. It is a subclass of a dict, and gives you a dictionary where the values correspond to the number of observations of each type of key:

```
a =  ['a.xxx', 'b.yyy', 'c.zzz', 'a.yyy', 'b.xxx', 'a.www']
from collections import Counter
Counter([item.split(".")[0] for item in a])
```

gives

```
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

which is what you require